# how can I select top 2 or 3 books price without using 'top' operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

I have a table called books with (book_name , price)  I am using SQL SERVER 2008
I need to get top 2 books that they have maximum prices

I have used this :

```
 Select * From bb n  Where (Select Count(book) From bb  
    Where   book <> n.book
      And
        price >  n.price
        ) >=2 // or 3  it must be flexible
```

but gives me incorrect answer  :( .

not allowed to use  'top' operation or order by  or OLAP functions
just simple query ..

Comment: Seriously, what reason do you have to avoid `order by`? O.o

Comment: Jan Van Herck, it's probably a homework question.

Comment: @Tony: and I'm the one who learned something from it :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could use ranking functions instead of `top`

```
 with cte as(

    select *,row_number() over(order by price desc) as price from table
    )

    select * from cte where price<=2
```

Comment: not allowed to use
over(order by price desc)

please read my question before answering

Comment: @Maria : why is that `over(order by price desc) is not allowed` you tagged `sql server ` see you question

Comment: I do not what to use it

Comment: @Maria what do you mean "not allowed"? Is this homework? Did the course materials not provide any insight into how you should go about solving this without using the approaches it forbids (which happen to be the most efficient and intuitive methods)?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: I do not encourage anyone to follow the techniques described in this post in any real-life situation. I pursued this question only for it's theoretical challenge.**

I suppose this is a theoretical / textbook / homework question, I can't think of a reason to **not** use `order by` in a real life situation, but here goes:

```
SELECT * FROM bb
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM bb)
OR price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM bb WHERE price < (SELECT MAX(price) FROM bb))
```

Note that this will produce more than 2 rows if your price column is not unique. You can fix this but then it's getting sort of complicated :D

```
;WITH ids AS
(
    SELECT id FROM bb
    WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM bb)
    OR price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM bb 
        WHERE price < (SELECT MAX(price) FROM bb))
)
SELECT * FROM bb
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids)
OR id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM ids))
```

However, if you really just want the top 2 **prices** you can do it like this:

```
SELECT MAX(price) as price FROM bb
UNION
SELECT MAX(price) FROM bb WHERE price < (SELECT MAX(price) FROM bb)
```

**edit #62**
Okay, I figured it out, took me long enough. You even had me mucking around with recursive cte's until I realized it is really as simple as assigning a rank to each record and throwing out the trash. This query is **highly** inefficient, but it meets all of your requirements up till now. Also note that the results are not ordered. That is precisely what `order by` is for :D

```
DECLARE @NumberOfRecords int
SET @NumberOfRecords = 3

;WITH bb_extended AS
(
    SELECT
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM bb AS bb2
            WHERE bb2.price > bb.price
            OR (bb2.price = bb.price AND bb2.id < bb.id)
        ) AS rank,
        *
    FROM
        bb
)
SELECT * FROM bb_extended
WHERE rank <= @NumberOfRecords
```

You can even condense this further (but you lose the rank information):

```
DECLARE @NumberOfRecords int
SET @NumberOfRecords = 3

SELECT * FROM bb WHERE @NumberOfRecords > (
        SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM bb AS bb2
        WHERE bb2.price > bb.price
        OR (bb2.price = bb.price AND bb2.id < bb.id)
    )
```

**Seriously. Do not do this.**

Comment: I need to be flixible some times I need top 3  or 4 or 5